# How to configure different logback levels to different appenders?

Tags: logging, logback

How can I configure something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- file and file-debug appenders definitions using RollingFileAppender -->

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
        <appender-ref level=debug ref="file-debug" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I know this example is invalid, but it is just to show what I want to achieve. **I need to save the debug output into another appender**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<appender name="file"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    ...
</appender>
<appender name="file-debug" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="file-debug" />
</root>
```